# How to dynamically edit VBO's on the fly

Tags: opengl, vbo

I am looking for a way to dynamically edit the data that displays for a vertex buffer object. I have tried glBufferSubData, glMapBuffer, glBufferData, and some others, however had no luck. I have found that the time consuming method is glBindBuffer. I think I am using VBOs right, but I am not completely sure. Heres some sample code of my problem:

```
    verticesId = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    normalsId  = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    texturesId  = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturesId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturesBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

the verticesBuffer and other variables are the FloatBuffers that have the data in them. Next, I render them this way:

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesId);
    glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturesId);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, amountOfVertices);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Here is how I edit the VBOs:

```
    int position = 0;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesId);

    mapBuffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY, null);

    verticesBuffer = mapBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

    verticesBuffer.position(position);

    // ... edit some values in the 'vertices' float array ...

    verticesBuffer.put(vertices);

    verticesBuffer.rewind();

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Is there any way to speed up the glBindBuffer method, or am I doing this wrong? And also, how should I edit the data for the most efficiency.

Comment: can you provide some code where you actually change those VBOs? or maybe you recreate them every frame?

Comment: Sorry its a little vague. I am trying to get only the parts I need out of some big code.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the drawing part by using [Vertex Array Objects](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt).

About the uploading part, your code is fine; what you can do is "double buffering": keep a copy of the data, process it using another thread (multiple processor system are frequent nowadays), and then upload with *glBufferSubData*.

Another option is the use of SIMD assembly, but this depends on your application.